# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rnn_cell'

Tags: python, tensorflow

PLEASE HELP ME

```
tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(self.model_parameters["num_bidirectional_units"])
```

the code:[deep_voice_2](https://github.com/jdbermeol/deep_voice_2)

python:2.7.5 tensorflow:1.1.0

Comment: You should update your tensorflow version.

Answer (score -1):

@Abhishek Bansal

thank you, and i do `pip install -U tensorflow`